# CSS Hover bug, overlay fluctuating effect on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place one overlay div over another so that on hover on the card div displays overlay div above it. But on hover, I don't know why there is some bug which creates a fluctuating effect before displaying the overlay div.

```css
.overlay {
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: -2;
 height: 290px;
 width: 240px;
 background: #000;
 border-radius: 30px; 
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 position: relative;
 top: -310px;
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
.card:hover + .overlay {
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 1;
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card" style="background: #fff; height: 290px; width: 240px; border-radius: 30px; display: inline-block; margin:20px; box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(112,112,112,0.2);"><img src="thumb.png" height="60%;"></div>
 <div class="overlay"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think it will work if you warp them and use the `parent:hover > .overlay` instead of selecting the next element like you do now (Edit: Coli's answer is better)

Comment: The problem is that you are putting another element _over_ your hovered element - which makes your mouse cursor now rest on this element, meaning the other one is _not_ in its hover state any more … Make that overlay a descendant of the triggering element to avoid this. (Hovering a descendant element always automatically means hovering the ancestor as well.)

Comment: if you put your overlay inside the card, then you could position it absolutely to the card (therefore not needed the manual minus top) and this would solve your hover problem

Comment: here is an example - easier way to line up your overlay to be on top of the card too: http://jsfiddle.net/waxzes0j/

Comment: @Pete why you don't post this as an answer?

Comment: @Coli OP should have accepted the answer below  - this is just a suggestion - not sure if the OP actually wants the overlay to completely cover the card as it is moved 20px higher than the card in the question

Comment: Okay, but I think a solution as child of `.card` would have many benefits. Better transition is one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the `z-index` of the overlay increases by hovering the `.card`. But now you no longer hovering the `.card`, you are hovering the `.overlay` and so it disappears.
To fix this, you should add a `.overlay:hover` style too:

```css
.overlay {
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: -2;
 height: 290px;
 width: 240px;
 background: #000;
 border-radius: 30px; 
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 position: relative;
 top: -310px;
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
.card:hover + .overlay, .overlay:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 1;
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="background: #fff; height: 290px; width: 240px; border-radius: 30px; display: inline-block; margin:20px; box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(112,112,112,0.2);"><img src="thumb.png" height="60%;"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to prevent the overlay from catching events (hover in this case) by using `pointer-events: none;` so that you don't lose the initial hover applied to the card:

```css
.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 290px;
  width: 240px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -310px;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.card:hover+.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.card {
  background: red;
  height: 290px;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

You can also simplify your code using pseudo element:

```css
.card:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  top:20px;
  right:20px;
  left:-20px;
  bottom:-20px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.card:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.card {
  position:relative;
  background: red;
  height: 290px;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution too. But you should mention, that every content on `.overlay` isn't clickable then.

Comment: @coli already said: *to prevent the overlay from catching events*

Comment: I don't think that's clear enough to understand that you can't click links on it anymore.